# Date-range-presets with SwiftUI's new MultiDatePicker

Tags: ios, swiftui, date-range, daterangepicker, multidatepicker

Using iOS16.3, XCode14.2, Swift5.7.2,

I try to create a nice looking Date-Picker where you can tap on a starting date and then tap on an ending date. And the entire date-range shall be highlighted.

Since this does not seem to exist even with the new MultiDatePicker under iOS16 and SwiftUI, I wonder if there is a good library out there to fulfill that task.

Moreover, I would like to add presets of DateRanges, such as `this week`, `last week`, `this month`, `last month` etc.

Here is what I tried in Code to achieve the `week` preset (see code below).

The problem is that once the user taps into the dates, then the preset-button no longer works.

Any idea how to achieve all this ?

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar
    @Environment(\.timeZone) var timeZone

    var bounds: Range<Date> {
        let start = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(
            timeZone: timeZone, year: 2022, month: 6, day: 1))!
        let end = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(
            timeZone: timeZone, year: 2023, month: 6, day: 30))!
        return start ..< end
    }

    @State var dates: Set<DateComponents> = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MultiDatePicker("Dates Available", selection: $dates, in: bounds)
            HStack {
                Button {
                    dates = []
                    let calendar = Calendar.current
                    let startDateComponents = DateComponents(year: 2023, month: 1, day: 15)
                    let endDateComponents = DateComponents(year: 2023, month: 2, day: 10)
                    let startDate = calendar.date(from: startDateComponents)!
                    let endDate = calendar.date(from: endDateComponents)!
                    
                    var currentDate = startDate
                    while currentDate <= endDate {
                        dates.insert(calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: currentDate))
                        currentDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
                    }
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("week")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try/look at my version of `RKCalendar` at: https://github.com/workingDog/RKCalendar 
that I modified for my own purpose many years ago.

Comment: very good, thank you!  the RKCalendar can't install with the Package Manager under iOS16.3 anymore, it seems. But I was able to take the code as files into my code-base to work with it. Great work. With the `mode = .dateRange` it works.

Comment: strange you have difficulties using SPM with my version of RKCalendar. I just tested this and it works for me on Xcode 14.2, macos 13.2, target ios 16.3.

Comment: see my screenshot below with the failure message....

Answer (score 0):

@workingdog:

Here is the screenshot when trying to add RKCalendar with SPM:

[image]

Ah and by the way: as an improvement, I suggest the following small changes to your horizontalView.

If you are using `isContinuous = false` and `isVertical = false` then I suggest the following replacements:

1. replace:

`ScrollView(.horizontal)` by `ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)`

and 2. replace:

`HStack` by `HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0)`

This makes the PageView fit into the center (and is not off by some strange offset once you swipe).

```
public var horizontalView: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
// change-suggestions here.....
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
// and change-suggestions here.....
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(pages) { page in
                    page.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                }
            }
        }
        .content.offset(x: isGestureActive ? offset : -geometry.size.width * CGFloat(index))
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: nil, alignment: .leading)
        .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged({ value in
                isGestureActive = true
                offset = value.translation.width - geometry.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            })
            .onEnded({ value in
                if abs(value.predictedEndTranslation.width) >= geometry.size.width / 2 {
                    var nextIndex: Int = (value.predictedEndTranslation.width < 0) ? 1 : -1
                    nextIndex += index
                    index = nextIndex.keepIndexInRange(min: 0, max: pages.endIndex - 1)
                }
                withAnimation { offset = -geometry.size.width * CGFloat(index) }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { self.isGestureActive = false }
            })
        )
    }.onAppear(perform: { index = todayIndex() })
}
```

Comment: I was talking about my version of RKCalendar at: https://github.com/workingDog/RKCalendar 
from your screenshot, you are installing the original version.

I have not worked on this for many years, and there are a lot of improvements and upgrades that can be done.
Thanks for the suggestions, feel free to improve the code and make it available to everyone. 
I have somewhat lost interest in this, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Ah, the fact that you did not adapt the readMe with the new SPM link confused me. All good, your version of the RKCalendar installs now just fine with SPM. Thank you.

Comment: yes it is a bit confusing. I'll update the README and at the same time include your suggestions. Thanks.